# How can a high school student value a possible degree?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, education

[From another question I asked](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90865/is-it-foolish-to-borrow-2-5x-income), an answer said:

> If a person borrowed heavily to obtain an education where they make anything less than 75K per year then it was probably foolish. There are many jobs that earn that and more that do not require a college education. A person would be far better off working while in school instead of borrowing for a relatively low income.

Some of the comments to this question had opinions either for or against this position:

> The idea that borrowing "heavily to obtain an education where they make anything less than 75K per year is foolish" is just plain wrong. Maybe if you live in California or one of the major East coast cities then this applies, but not if you live somewhere with much lower cost of living. Not to mention the value of a good education beyond just securing a job.

and

> It doesn't matter how high the cost of living is in the place you're going to work if your job isn't even able to pay your student loans. Getting a loan now to pick a very badly-paid job in the future isn't a wise move. A former GF is still paying her student loans five years after finishing college with monthly payments of $900, and she still has five more years to go. Her monthly salary is around $700. She has to consistently borrow money from everyone around her to just pay off her loans. The worst part? That's a good salary for her field.

In high school they tell us that college is valuable even if we don't get a high income ("it's about signaling"). A few of these replies seem to imply the opposite and I wish I had heard some of these other views before I began college (are current high school students hearing this?). These replies dumbfounded me a bit, as I've always heard that student loans were justifiable debt, yet a few of these replies state otherwise.

Since student loans may be a part of higher education and these affect personal finance situations, what should students consider about taking on student loan debt before getting a degree, such as, is Pete correct that 75K income for a potential degree (career path) is not enough to justify student loan debt?

Comment: An unfortunate truth often not spoken in these discussions is that your available safety net *heavily* impacts the profitability of going to get a post-secondary degree. Consider whether an answer to this question (here, or in society at large) assumes that you have, for example, the ability to live at home with your parents on graduation. Consider if you have the ability to work where you are, or if you would have to move to get work in that field [thus increasing initial cashflow costs as well as the emotional burden]. Too often these privileges are taken for granted by those giving advice.

Comment: For someone with a strong safety net and parental support, often even a vague liberal arts degree with associated debt can be a good idea for improving your life. For someone 100% on their own, often the economic priorities of making your degree 'pay for itself' become the overriding decider. So make sure you always view life advice from the lens of your own personal situation, not necessarily from the 'national average'.

Comment: High school guidance counselors are a scourge on humanity.  Go to the "best" school you can get in to, cost be damned, then don't consider the economic opportunities that degree may offer.  And now, big shocker, when you don't underwrite debt and it's non-dischargeable in bankruptcy we're on the brink of a student loan crisis and have mortgaged the future of an entire generation for the benefit of teacher union pensions a bunch of private schools.

Comment: First, understand that the value of a degree depends largely upon the individual. Then research BLS statistics for jobs of interest: https://www.bls.gov/ooh/a-z-index.htm  Then I'd research the industry, does which school you choose matter for that industry? For most jobs, it doesn't really matter, for some it definitely does. Then you can research price and get an idea of whether or not the student loans are a good investment. Try to find some people who work in your desired field and see if they wish they had done things differently school-wise. Unfortunately not easy to nail down simply.

Comment: The key phrase here is "borrow heavily".  Most of what we hear about people with student loan problems is from people who borrowed large amounts, went to a big-name school, and majored in a field that's oversupplied.  (Harvard Law comes to mind...)  We don't hear about the people who borrowed $10-20K, went to the local state U, got a degree in STEM, and had a decently-paying internship starting in their junior year.

Comment: @jamesqf That is a very good point.  Not everyone borrowed $100K.  That's a great additional comment.

Comment: While this isn't universally true, high paying jobs that don't require a lot of education are disproportionately severely taxing on your body. Try calculating lower medical costs, higher workforce time-span (how long you can physically perform your job), and the extra years of your life you could gain by going to college.

Comment: One of the claims quoted by the OP has the person making less than minimum wage. On top of that, the claim goes on to state that the pay is good for her field. Seems like somebody is exaggerating or just plain making things up. Or, giving the benefit of doubt, it could just be that the person being quoted didn't attend college and math is a bit of a challenge for them because of it.

Comment: >"In high school they tell us that college is valuable even if we don't get a high income" A friend who made millions selling aluminum siding for houses, would tell people that aluminum siding was a good thing.

Comment: "student loans" are simply the biggest scam of our era - the latest part of the "Banking-Government complex".

Comment: why not,  instead, move to any of the western countries offering good degrees at reputable institutions for 1/10000th of the cost of a degree in USA and get the life changing experience of living abroad at the same time? i never see those kinds of dilemmas here.

Comment: @CptEric Most countries that aren't the UK or Ireland don't offer undergraduate courses in english for most fields. Masters/PHD sure, but if you want to study anywhere else in an undergraduate program you should better be fluent in the native language (or at least have a plan of how to become fluent quickly). Of course on the other hand, if you are planning to stay in a country for several years learning the language is kind of necessary anyway, and there's no quicker way to learn a language than being forced to use it every day, but it's still a concern.

Comment: @Cubic germany, uk, france and netherlands offer english undergrad programmes.

Comment: @CptEric Sometimes, yes. Not in general and certainly not for all courses.

Comment: @CptEric +1000.  The distance also helps give you focus.  US citizen, the USA is not your friend.  It will give you liberty and the pursuit of happiness which means basically it will leave you alone.   Everything is on you. It will also "leave alone" the pure capitalists who make a raging mess of college financing and healthcare with greedy practices which have led to borrowing a fortune to go to school.  If you can eject from this for a few years and get an education, definitely do.

Comment: "In high school they tell us that college is valuable even if we don't get a high income" You mean teachers and other educators believe the world begins and ends with education? To a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: @Fattie: That's simply nonsense.  Sure, some people misuse them, borrowing more than they can reasonably expect to pay, but for a lot of people they're a path to a much better income.  I certainly wouldn't be borderline wealthy today if I hadn't been able to borrow about $10K in student loans.

Comment: @CptEric: So where exactly is a non-wealthy American supposed to get the money to move to one of those countries that offer "free" education?  And support themselves for the 4 years it's going to take to get a degree?  Even assuming those "free" college educations are available to non-citizens, most countries will not let you work without a permit, which is hard to get unless you have special skills.  (I have done it, BTW: worked at a European research institute associated with a well-regarded university.  Doubt I could have gotten in if they hadn't headhunted me.)

Comment: @jamesqf as per spain, you apply to a university, they do most of your paperwork, and you can find a job with that permit, not only that, if the stay is less 5 years  you can apply to a residence permit, that is renewable to unlimited ( for live) after those  5 years, and that grants all rights a citizien might have.  he's gonna get the money just the same way a non-wealthy american is supposed to pay for 80K/year of local university fees, it'll just be way less money. rent prices, living costs, and uni fees are 2x-10x smaller anywhere on europe except london and paris.

Comment: @Cubic  these are UAB's (autonomous university of barcelona) full english undergrad programmes. http://www.uab.cat/web/study/undergraduate/undergraduate-offer/bachelor-s-degrees-in-english-1345667078818.html   the others may vary in %. any student EU national or not can apply to both equity grant ( a 0-interest, pay as you can grant) or a scholarship grant ( all credits are paid by the government, free education). to get the 2nd you must mantain over 6.5/10 average grades, pass atleast 32 credits per semester, and is almost always given if you go over 8/10.

Comment: @CptEric I didn't say that there are no english undergraduate courses, I said that you can't expect them in general. Especially the larger universities will have bigger undergrad programmes of course. The point was that you can't necessarily expect to have courses offered in english, which is why you'd need to check if that is a problem for you.

Comment: yeah, just wanted to add in a few cents more of data, hehe. it is totally not unfeasible to do that,  and it's maybe because of lack of information that i presume most don't do it. i wouldn't imagine myself having paid more than 6K/year for college, and that's just if i had been very very very bad student dropping classes & missing all deadlines.  half (or 1/4) of what the average american student spends in university fees per year is worth an academic life ( bsc -> msc -> phd) in most european countries, if private avg. ( >50k/y), then also living costs included.

Comment: Just as another (potentially useless) data point, in Germany, total costs of student life per year are around 10500 USD. That includes tuition, room, various fees and so on. Furthermore, students can work up to 20 hours per week and can get salary of $560 per year tax-free! Due to tax benefits for employers, such positions are numerous. So the part-time job can cover a bit more than half of the yearly expenses for a student.

Comment: As AndrejaKo stated, in Germany, studying at universities is free of charge, even for people from abroad. It might not be your first plan, but you should consider to study here in Germany without drowning in debts :) Education shouldn't be a matter of money at all...

Comment: @AndrejaKo i think it's  570€ per month, 4 hours a day, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: @CptEric Actually, it's 450€ per month(450€-Basis or Minijob) for the tax-free part, and the limit is actually for a week. This is important, due to work-time planning. For example, during my masters, I often had lectures for 4 days a week, and in theory I could work 8 hours on the two remaining work days without any problems from the immigration authorities. There is also a classification between "Studentische Hilfskraft" (less than 40 hours a month) and Werkstudent (more than 40 hours a month), but that's relevant for work contracts and not for immigration itself.

Comment: @AndrejaKo that's quite cool. here in spain you are free to get any job, but class attendance is mandatory.  if your job is a paid training internship ( 6 months to 2 years), your company pays 20% of the taxes it should have paid to a normal worker with the same entry experience ( zero ), and you pay just 4% of income tax, so it's pretty much tax-less too.

Comment: Also, even if you can get 75K at a job you might want to pursue a degree to have a more fun/easy/less risky job. i.e you might not want to work as a corrections officer due to risks, or as a plumber due to dirtiness or a porn star due to social ramifications or personal morale.

Also if you do something you enjoy you will probably do a better job and by doing so having bigger chance of promotion/higher salary.

Comment: @CptEric Non-US degrees tend to be cheaper, so on that point, you're right as far as cost benefit.

Comment: @CptEric: Re "80K/year of local university fees", where on Earth did you get that number from?   At my local, it's $7535/yr, which can be offset by a Pell Grant of up to $5775, plus other aid.  WRT to getting a job in Spain, per Google the unemployment rate is currently over 16% (down from 25% in 2012) so good luck with that!  I don't know about living costs in Spain, but in Switzerland I was paying more for a single room (converted from a pool house) than my US mortgage payment on a fairly sizeable place.

Comment: @jamesqf  i am already employed, but thanks. unemployment only affects unskilled workforce (26% of spain's workforce), there's a giant shortage  of STEM positions. the cost of life in spain (excl: barcelona city) is ~400€/mo for a 60/70m2 3-room flat rent, 200€ for electricity + internet + city gas + bulding fees,  and ~100€ of food per person. the international cost of life measurement unit, 1L of milk, is at 0.65€. for the university fees, i googled "average US university fees", which gave me  10K-24K for (public?) state universities, 60K for private, and ~80K for elite (harvard?berkeley?)

Comment: @jamesqf and given that the marginal difference between university costs in spain never exceeds ~2K,  it's *atleast* 8 times cheaper to study in the best public institution of spain (  or france, or germany, or UK as a CS in oxford is just 10.2K/y) than in the best american university, in the end to just get a paper confirming you know N stuff. unless you want to pursue an elitist field, but then you're not a low-income american student. and  as i said, grants in spain and france can reduce the fees, if you're a good student, to 0. not 5K (Pell grant?), not 10K (University scolarship?), 0.

Comment: @CptEric: So if I follow your logic, you got a job in Spain, which means you are not an unskilled worker, no?  But virtually all low-income American students would be unskilled workers, pretty much by definition.  (Because if they had marketable skills, they wouldn't be low-income, would they?)  For prices, at today's exchange rate, 1€ = $1.2324, so call it $1.25 to keep the math simple.  Now I just bought milk tonight: 1 US gallon ~= 4l for $3.48, so 0.70€, not a major difference.

Comment: @CptEric: WRT state university costs, I think you may be including out-of-state tuition in that average, making it more than double the in-state (- local) cost: https://trends.collegeboard.org/college-pricing/figures-tables/2017-18-state-tuition-and-fees-public-four-year-institutions-state-and-five-year-percentage  And of course the US has plenty of grants & scholarships that reduce costs, too.  I'm not sure what just what you mean by "elitist field": I certainly like to think of mine (CS, math & physics) as being elite:-)

Comment: @jamesqf  unskilled - not even high school, or primary school sometimes.   in switzerland the average milk 1L price is 2.40€, that's what we were comparing in our last conversation.        i don't know what "out of state" tuition is, but i presume or suppose it means you get to pay more if you're outsider. alas, i just pointed you to the averages, and they fit your graph. what if your state uni doesn't offer what you want to study? or it's masters are crap? as per elitist field,  i meant "a field that values more contacts and renown instead of knowledge". cs+math+physics sounds evil-y scary :D

Comment: @CptEric: The US is divided into 50 states, which (among many other things) primarily fund their university systems.  So if you go to a state university in your state of residence, you pay lower (often much lower) tuition, on the assumption that you (or your parents) have paid taxes to the state, and will continue to do so.  WRT Swiss milk prices, it's about 1.25€/l per this site: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Switzerland&displayCurrency=EUR

Comment: @jamesqf i used the same site the day i answered to you and it said 2.40€ for 1L of milk in Geneva,  someone must have updated it. it's still twice the price, though. let's compare it with barcelona: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Spain&country2=Switzerland&city1=Barcelona&city2=Geneva&tracking=getDispatchComparison

Comment: "Her monthly salary is around $700. She has to consistently borrow money from everyone around her to just pay off her loans. The worst part? That's a good salary for her field." If you work 40hr/week, that's about 180 hrs/month, so $700/month is $3.88 an hour. That's below federal minimum wage, at least for US. How is that a "good salary"?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> college is valuable even if we don't get a high income

Absolutely! Any education is valuable in some way. Not all are valuable *economically*, though. A degree in sociology that enables you to work in social services where you can impact peoples' lives for the better is invaluable, though it may not pay enough to pay back tens of thousands of dollars of student loans.

> I've always heard that student loans were justifiable debt

Not always. Borrowing $200K to get a Literal Arts degree (meaning a general degree with no specific specialization) from a private school is probably a bad idea. Borrowing $10K to finish your degree in Accounting is *easier* to justify financially, since it should be paid off within a year of getting a job.

The problem with a student loan is that it should be used to earn a degree where you can get a job that *pays back* the loan quickly. Once you have a student loan, there's no collateral to "give back" to satisfy the loan, unlike a mortgage or a car loan, and they cannot be discharged in bankruptcy. The only way out is to earn money and pay it back.

Yes, there are "loan forgiveness" programs out there that pay back your student loans if you work in an under-served field or region, but they usually require 5 to 10 years of work before the loan is paid off. By then, the interest you've paid usually outweighs the amount that is forgiven, and you'd have been better off (financially) getting a job that pays more and paying back the loan yourself, *then* working in an under-served area if you choose to.

I value a college education *very highly*, but that doesn't mean that borrowing as much as you can to get a degree from a prestigious school is always a good investment.

I personally want my children to avoid student debt like the plague for those reasons. As teenagers, I have already told them that I will only support them if they go to a school that we can afford together (which might mean they get a job to support themselves), pursue a degree that justifies the cost, and don't take any student debt. That may mean going to an in-state public university, but I have personally experienced the pain of paying back student loan debt over several years, and don't want my children to go through that if at all possible.

> is Pete correct that 75K income for a potential degree (career path) is not enough to justify student loan debt?

The number is fairly arbitrary so it depends on what your cost of living is. Making $75K in, say, Alabama, is much different than making $75K in New York City.  It's easier to live on much less than $75K with a lower cost-of-living and use the rest to pay off the student loans as quickly as possible.

> what should students consider about taking on student loan debt before getting a degree

The main *financial* consideration is: how much do I expect to earn with this degree versus without it? That requires four guesses, though: What kind of job can I get now, how much does it pay, what kind of job can I get with the degree, and how much does *it* pay. Take that difference and divide it into the amount you'll need to borrow, and that tells you *at least* how long it will take to pay off the loan (in reality the interest will make it a longer period). Since that analysis has to be done before beginning college, that's a lot of unknowns to gamble a large student debt burden on. I changed degrees three times in college (taking loans along the way), and paid for it later with a larger debt burden than I would have liked.

*Plus*, that assumes that you *don't spend any more of that extra money*. It's *very* tempting to desire a nicer house, nicer cars, etc. and put the student loans off to the side, which increases the payback period even more.

All that to say that there are way too many unknowns to know for certain whether a student loan can be completely justified. It's better to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: I really like your second paragraph.

Comment: @PeteB. Thanks, though I like your Russian Literature example better :)

Comment: Good thoughts, but this doesn't seem to answer the question. How does one determine the value of a potential degree?

Comment: Liberal Arts doesn't mean what you think it means. Liberal Arts is not a degree, it is a type of curriculum. You can get a "liberal arts" education in Engineering. All it means is that you fulfilled basic studies requirements along the way, like taking Sociology 101 and Foreign Language 101.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 Many schools have a 'College of Liberal Arts' or liberal arts department that houses majors like theater, music, English, history, philosophy, athropology, political science, etc. When someone says a Liberal Arts degree, I think that's typically understood to mean they majored in one of those.

Comment: @HartCO True, I've added my thoughts on that.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: You can't get a liberal arts education in Engineering, because engineering is also a type of curriculum, and this is enforced by accreditation (ABET).  Your point is still valid, you just picked a bad example.

Comment: I guess the "it depends" part is not just about the cost of living, but also about the size of the loan. As said before, a $200000 loan is different to a $10000 one.

Comment: You absolutely can get a liberal arts education while majoring in Engineering. In fact, most college students in the last 20 years have.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: You're now talking about completing two curricula.  An engineering degree that requires over 110 credit hours in STEM coursework doesn't leave time for 50+ credits of liberal arts.  (For reference, graduation in engineering is a total of 130-135 credit hours, while most other degrees are 120-125.  A program with Engineering and a liberal arts education, at 160+ credits, is effectively a multiple degree.)  Four classes in the arts and social sciences to meet distribution requirements do not constitute a liberal arts education.

Comment: Every person with a Bachelor's Degree that took credits beyond the "major coursework" has a liberal arts education. Which covers just about every BS and BA graduate in the last couple decades.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: No, there's a big difference between a well-rounded education, and a liberal arts degree.  Just as the liberal arts major who takes a few 100 and 200 level math & science courses to fulfill breadth requirements isn't getting a STEM degree.

Comment: @WakeDemons3: Actually, that is (in theory) exactly the difference between a BS and BA degree in the same field. The first emphasizes depth, the second emphasizes breadth. And the liberal arts curriculum is far more than 4-5 classes as part of a distribution requirement / general education requirement. There are no BA degrees in engineering (maybe "engineering science" or "engineering technology", however these are not accredited engineering degrees), and for an engineering student to meet the breadth requirements associated with any of the BA degrees in other fields would add 2-3 semesters.

Answer (score 18):

Great question.  The first thing one needs to realize is that college education and high student loans are independent of one another.  One can obtain a degree with little or no debt (and no help from relatives).  Also one does not need to obtain a degree to achieve a high income.  Unfortunately, the financial aid offices of most college encourage indebtedness, which is horrible for young and impressionable minds.

There are numerous web sites that can outline careers and their qualifications.  Things will change but generally speaking engineers and health care related fields start out with good salaries and have good upward mobility.

But lets say your interest is in Russian Literature, and you would really like to take classes in that.  Obtaining a degree in such will not really improve your earning ability unless one obtains a PhD.  So why not start a career in your chosen field (that does not require a degree) and take classes in this desirable area of study?  You can cash flow the cost and there is really no need to obtain such an esoteric degree so you can avoid matriculates in which you have no interest.

Another path is if a person desires to own and run a HVAC company.  Should they take business classes?  Yes, for sure.  Do they need to take biology and philosophy in order to obtain a Business Administration degree?  No, those things are probably a waste of time.  They would be far better off working, learning the technical part of the job, building contacts that will be valuable later, and taking some business classes on the side.

Income earning capacity, no matter what the degree, will almost always come down to work ethic, time management, and working with others.  Why not make work part of your college education?  Sure go to classes, but there is nothing wrong with working too.

For students without parental help it is best to stick to only state schools and to start off at a community college.  Apply for scholarships and work.  If you have to take loans, take the minimum and only for less than half of tuition and books.  Any more than that and you have to reevaluate your goals.  I live in a college town and see many college students driving really nice cars that were bought courtesy of student loans.  That is foolish no matter what the income potential.

Comment: I appreciate your comments about general education classes. As someone who took on extra student debt so that I could waste time and money on classes that would never help me in my field, this hits really close to home.

Comment: Funny you mention HVAC.  Met someone recently who owned their own HVAC business (no college at all) and I was stunned how much they made.  Never even heard of HVAC before them, but now I see them everywhere.

Comment: I live in Florida, and it would be my choice for a career without a college degree.  Many have heaters for their pools and home, the career is a gold mine.

Comment: @1006a they are mutually exclusive or independent events.  One can have a great education and no loans, or one can have loans and no real education.

Comment: Mutually exclusive means you can't have both things, so in this case you are saying someone cannot have both a college education and high student loans, which we all know to be false.

Comment: @Pete B.: mutually exclusive => XOR | independent event = OR, please change, currently its confusing

Comment: *Owning* an HVAC business has nothing to do with being an HVAC worker... No sh** a business owner can be filthy rich. But all the HVAC WORKERS I know make about 18 bucks an hour (25,000/year take home). Whoopty doo.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 Many small business _owners_ become that way by working in that trade for many years, learning how the business runs and either taking over an existing business or starting their own. It doesn't often happen right after high school, but does not require a 4-year business degree.

Comment: @D Stanley: The flip side of that is that only a small fraction of people who work in those businesses will ever wind up owning one, much less a successful one.

Comment: "Should they take business classes? Yes, for sure. Do they need [a degree] No, those things are probably a waste of time. They would be far better off working, learning the technical part of the job, building contacts that will be valuable later, and taking some business classes on the side."  -- this is only true if you aren't going to be working for an employer or trying to get loans from a bank that considers having a degree to make you more employable or credit-worthy.  Sometimes even a degree in an unrelated field is deemed more merit-worthy than just taking a few related classes.

Answer (score 11):

"It depends" would be an understatement, because "It **really, really** depends." We all know people that never went to college that are very financially successful and we also all know people that went to college (and graduated) that aren't financially successful. Some college majors are inherently worth more than others, and some industries put more value on what school your degree is from (for example Business and Law).

I personally had over $80K in debt when I graduated and I consider my education to be the best investment I ever made. On the flip side I know quite a few people that had much less debt than I did and regret going at all, though most of them do value the "life experience" even though they don't feel it was worth the financial investment. Despite the fact that it worked out well for me, there are definitely things I could have done differently, for example:

1. I went to an expensive private school. I could have gone to a highly rated community college nearby for two years and then transferred the credits to the 4 year school. I likely would have still finished in 4 years but could have knocked $30K off my debt that way.
2. I could have worked harder in school. I know many people that regret not working hard enough in school, but I don't know anyone that regrets working too hard. Had I had a stronger work ethic perhaps I could have completed my degrees in less time by taking on extra courses.
3. Or, instead of extra courses I could have spent that time working. I had a few part time jobs but had I picked up a regular job I could have significantly reduced my debt once I graduated. I didn't feel like I had a lot of free time while I was in school, but looking back and comparing it to now having a family and working full time, I realize I had **a lot** of free time in college that I didn't take advantage of.

Comment: It really, really depends. So true. I'm like you, wish I had done things less expensively, but I bet there are people who regret not taking on more debt, like working your way through undergrad and law school could feel wise, but incurring the undergrad debt and focusing more on being top of your class can lead to better law school options. I'd wager graduating from Harvard Law with $200k in debt is vastly better than graduating debt-free from a middle-tier school.

Comment: To prove your point: I personally graduated with a BA in Economics and ~80k in student debt. I currently work as an industrial programmer, and consider my degree to be valuable for reasons other than financial. It has done precisely 0 for my career, but has helped me tremendously in day to day life. Had I not gotten my current job, I would have called that degree the biggest mistake of my life.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are a number of good answers to this already, and they make some good points.  But I think you are also asking a question that does not have a single answer and cannot be directly answered, and so you will at best get guidance to finding your own answer.  To summarize some existing points and add to them, consider the following:

**How are you choosing your degree?**

I had an acquaintance who graduated with a BS from a 4 year college in something like Greek History.  I met him because he worked for minimum wage in a business my parents had recently purchased.  Another friend graduated from a 4 year college with a degree in mechanical engineering, and at that same time was working for Bayer for somewhere around $60k per year (in an area with a very low cost of living).

Whether you're choosing your degree based on high paying career prospects or just what interests you plays a large role in a cost benefit analysis.  Unless you are independently wealthy, I recommend you always choose a career first, and let your choice of degree follow from that.

**How much do you really need to spend?**

I have two acquaintances who worked in college financial aid offices.  They were specifically trained not to help students determine how much they need, but to help them determine how much they can get.  In many cases a student could survive on a $100k loan, but they qualified for $150k.  The FA office would encourage them to take the $150k, and then the students, having no experience in personal finances, would use the extra money as disposable income during their college life.  In essence, this increased their cost of college by 50%.

Similarly, many students move away from home, as much as doubling their financial outlay for the degree.  If you have the option of commuting from your parents' house, consider it and how it affects you financially.

Similarly, community colleges offer a great education in many areas for as much as 90% less than universities, and an Associates Degree will transfer to most universities.  When you finish your BA no one will know or care that you spent your first two years at a CC; just that you achieved your BA from the university.  Consider this as well.

So determining how much you actually need and financing that, as opposed to taking all that is recommended or offered, plays a large role in a cost benefit analysis.

**Is financing really your only income source**

Many students are surprised by just how much money is available via scholarships.  Many are for academic or athletic achievement, but there are also many that are not.  Consider which you may qualify for and which you may qualify for if you work towards that goal.  If scholarships reduce your degree cost by 50%, that must be taken into your account in your cost benefit analysis.

Similarly, many students consider working and college to be mutually exclusive.  For many, they need not be.  All degrees differ in the study time required, as do all students.  But many students can easily work a part time job during school.  Assuming a pay rate of $10 / hour, and a a work schedule of 15 hours per week during school semesters (9 months of the year) and 40 hours per week during breaks, the student will have a annual gross income of $10,200, or $40,800 over the course of the four year degree.  In other words, attending college does not always mean you need to sacrifice earning potential as an opportunity cost.  Consider this in your cost benefit analysis.

**Some further calculations and statistics**

I think you may find some of the calculations and statistics I posted in my question at https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/28167/should-i-financially-assist-my-child-in-paying-for-college to be very useful.

**What is value?**

As has been mentioned, a degree, especially one from a university that provides a breadth of knowledge, is invaluable.  Having the capacity to understand the world around you, understand the foundations of business and politics, and having a springboard for further study, can change your life in fundamental ways you cannot imagine.  Not to mention the educational basis for any potential later life career switch.

Careers that require degrees also often include better benefits, more vacation time, paid sick leave, retirement contributions, increased scheduling flexibility, and other intangibles.  Some jobs without degree requirements also include some of these, but many do not.

Consider that even if there is no economic value, a degree may still be worth many tens of thousands of dollars in the way it enriches your life.

**Is this correct?**

> is Pete correct that 75K income for a potential degree (career path) is not enough to justify student loan debt?

No.  This is absolutely incorrect, simply due to the fact that there are so very many variables involved.  For instance, someone who finishes college with no debt due to scholarships and part time work can justify the degree even if their pay remains unchanged.  Any answer that puts a simple number on such a complex question is flat out wrong.

I consider this especially egregious considering that where I live (low cost of living) an annual salary of $75k would be considered 'wealthy', and about double what the average individual earns.

**Some Steps**

Much of what has been presented is very "consider this", so some concrete steps to take to figure all this out may be in order.  I would recommend you do this:

1) Determine the statistically average pay for the career you will likely end up in without a degree.  This is easily found on Google.

2) Choose a career you may be interested in and look up the statistically average pay for that career.

3) Determine the degree and schooling you need to work in that career.

4) Determine the cost of that schooling.  Take into account cost saving measures (commuting, community colleges, etc) and income opportunities (scholarships, part time work, etc) to minimize the cost.  Use this formula to determine what you would need to borrow: (tuition + boarding + food + transportation) - ((part time job income - expenditures) + scholarships + savings).

5) Determine interest on the amount you would need to borrow and use this formula to determine total cost of schooling: borrowed amount + interest + income from work you would have done had you not gone to school

6) Now use this formula to determine the value of schooling: (annual salary of career - annual salary of uneducated career) * 50

7) Now use this formula to determine whether the degree is worthwhile: value of schooling - total cost of schooling.  If the number is positive, your degree is worthwhile.  Remember, this is a purely fiscal determination!  It does not take into account comfort, happiness, or other intangibles.

8) Now determine if you can repay your loans in a reasonable amount of time.  Use this formula: Repayment period = amount borrowed / (annual net salary of career - annual net salary of uneducated career).  For this step you can estimate net pay as 75% of gross pay

Statistically speaking, if you are fiscally responsible, and choose a target career instead of choosing a degree, it should always be worthwhile.

Comment: You have to read Pete's claim in context.  The discussion was about debt equal to 2.5 times household income.  Applying your steps, with a salary equal to double the median, that kind of debt is still going to take 10 years to pay off... and that kind of horizon isn't justified unless you are getting double the median.

Comment: @BenVoigt I disagree.  I think 10-15 years is a perfectly reasonable and expected horizon for repayment.  I would go so far as to say that 30-40 years is acceptable, given that after that time your income will be higher than it was (fiscally justified) and you will have gained innumerable intangibles from having the degree (personally justified).  Please reference the calculations in my linked question.  I'm curious: why do you consider 10 years an unreasonable repayment period?  Do you feel there is some other cost, or negative future repercussions, to getting a degree?

Comment: There are certainly opportunity costs to getting a degree, beyond the cost of the loans.  If you weren't taking out the loans for that degree, you could be spending your time on other training (better paying degree, similar degree at a cheaper program, or vocational school that teaches skills without a real "degree").  Or you could be getting experience at a job that doesn't require a degree.  30 years worth of debt is absolutely unconscionable to be saddling young people with; it is going to shape their life as much or more than the degree.

Comment: How is someone supposed to save for retirement if it takes them 40 years to break even on their student loans?  No, if the numbers are that bad, the dream of making a living doing what the person enjoys needs to give way to a career that will pay the bills efficiently, with enough (time and money) left over to do what the person enjoys.  But in most cases, simply opting for a school with lower tuition is the way to preserve the career choice while avoiding debt servitude.

Comment: @BenVoigt If it takes 40 years to break even (and I've never seen it take even half that if properly planned), and they work 41+ years, then they are in a better financial position than they would have been if they didn't get the degree. If they can't save for retirement in that situation, they similarly would not have been able to had they not gotten the degree, so it's immaterial to the discussion. If you want to debate whether that length of repayment is immoral, that's a different question entirely than what the OP asked here. We must deal with reality as it is, not as we want it to be.

Comment: @BenVoigt I do agree with your comment about opportunity costs, and other possibilities between "degree" and "no degree".  However, my answer was very long as is, and as I said this is a very complicated subject that entire books have been written on.  I think my answer gives a good foundation upon which to do calculations on those possibilities as well and compare from there.

Answer (score 4):

> I've always heard that student loans were justifiable debt, yet a few
>   of these replies state otherwise.

Only a Sith deals in absolutes. Nothing is guaranteed by taking out a student loan. You certainly aren't guaranteed to graduate.

> what should students consider about taking on student loan debt before
>   getting a degree, such as, is Pete correct that 75K income for a
>   potential degree (career path) is not enough to justify student loan
>   debt?

Consider what you value a degree in the field you are applying for. Ask yourself if you will be financially stable after you graduate.

Consider the fact that you are investing in not only yourself, but the job market as well. What do you think the market for your job will look like by the time you graduate? Some fields like medicine will always have demand. But consider the overall decrease in salary growth for IT positions.

Consider the need for the degree. Will your employer likely require a degree of sorts? Or is it possible to obtain your goal position through other work experience? Lawyers/doctors would never be able to consider the possibility of a passing their certifications without some formal education.

Consider your desires. Lots of current students want the college experience. That certainly would increase the value of attending if it's something you want.

It's always best not to take on debt. But in some cases, it's a fantastic tool to get to your goal (buying a house, buying a car, creating a business).

Comment: A Sith? Famous Celebrity Entertainer David Ramsey speaks in absolutes all the time. "There is not responsible use of credit cards", "If you owe money on cards, paying from low balance to high balance in that order is the only thing to do," among others. Davidian infallibility. Otherwise, +1 for you.

Comment: @ JoeTaxpayer, Of course, David Ramsey is usually dealing with people who are working to overcome incorrect ideas and bad habits regarding money. His advice is usually good, though often a little overstated for someone that is not deep in debt. (Plus, I love the irony that "Only a Sith deals in absolutes" is also an absolute statement, so Kenobi must be a Sith!)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on when you achieve that 75k income also.  Are you graduating with a bachelor's into a field where ~75k jobs are reasonably available to new grads?  Or is that 75k job after 10+ years of experience AND a bachelor's degree?

Is your expected field littered with 75k+ jobs for experienced professionals?  Or are there only a select few jobs that pay at that rate and the selection process for those positions is highly competitive?

Keep in mind also many teachers likely have student debt of their own.  This may lead them to a view that since they are scraping by, you will be just fine scraping by too.

Also consider these teachers are people and just want to go home after work.  Sticking with the canned answer of college == good may be earlier for them, since it's easy, available and likely reduces friction in these types of conversations they may have students.

Further consider what happens to them personally and professionally if they veer from the script of college being for everyone.  How many indignant parents call them angry, demanding answers and/or an apology for telling their precious child that college may not always be the best route.  Or if the school adminstration has issued an edict directing all faculty to never stray from a specific narrative.  Teachers may be in a hard spot and have to guard their own futures also.

Answer (score 2):

College is a two-part purchase. One part is a **financial investment**, which is your increased ability to pay for tuition and then turn a profit. The rest is **luxury**, which is anything that doesn't contribute to your ability to to pay for tuition. Many (including me) don't normally consider education to be a luxury, but since tuition is measured in dollars, the "value" of your degree must also be measured in your increased earning potential; everything else is "useless" or "consumption" from a finance perspective.

**Financial Investment:** A major goal of college is to increase your earning power. In a theoretical purely perfect-free-market world, the only people going to college would be those who could turn a profit on it (nobody else would get loans), and those coming from enough wealth to buy it outright. If you want to make a sound investment in college, by definition you need to turn a profit. If not, you would have been financially better off not having gone to college.

The two biggest factors that impact the financial investment aspect are the academic power of the university and your choice of major. High-powered institutions will be able to offer you major advantages that translate directly into market value, ranging from specialized areas of study, advanced curricula, access to top researchers, and connections to industry leaders. The area of study is probably even more important - a computer science graduate is primed for the job market; an English or sociology major won't have a career flow as naturally from their area of study.

Given these two factors, the calculation is simple - how lucrative is the field you want to study, and what kind of school are you going to? If you're going to be a starving artist, you can starve without being in debt. If you want to study mathematics and go into finance, the price tag on an Ivy League school is negligible. For everything in between, you have to determine how much your 4 years in college are worth relative to your life after that, as measured in dollars (e.g. If I get the same $100k/yr job, will it be worth an extra $500/mo for 10 years to have gone to X school over Y school? Maybe Y will only give me $80k/year? And so on.)

**Luxury**: As stated above, luxury is anything that doesn't directly contribute to the bottom line. Recreational clubs, sports, social life (parties), dorm quality, amenities, even the weather. Your entire degree can be a luxury, should you choose to study fine arts. Even a degree from Harvard is purely a luxury if you can't/don't get it to pay for itself.

You don't need to eschew luxury, but you must understand how much of your degree is luxury vs investment. If you don't, you're in for a world of surprise and pain. I will forever remember some amazing history and business classes I took, as well as a lot of the friends I made along the way. I also knew that nobody - not the university, the government, the banks, and not my future landlord - would accept happiness in place of dollar bills, so I also remember spending most of my time studying computer science and math.

**The bottom line**: Since tuition costs dollars, you must measure the value of your degree in dollars. Know what contributes to that dollar amount in your future projected earnings and what doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This chart, sourced from the article [Household income in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Household_income_in_the_United_States) offers a look at the difference one might expect from attaining a higher level education. Unfortunately, the WikiPedia article data is a bit old (2003), but it helps to compare differences in median income.

[image]

What's helpful is to think of this as the center number on a bell curve. It starts with thinking "half make more, half less" but also understanding that the 'above median' high school dropouts contains business owners who are in the top .1% of earners, and 'below median' members with advanced degrees who are serving up lattes at Starbucks.

This makes it tougher to *do the math* as one might be inclined to look at the numbers, take the extra income for a college grad, and calculate the net present value of such an increase. On reflection, that process may work in the aggregate, but not for the individuals who fall below the median in the group of those with higher education.

The other answers address the need to combine a look at the expense of college with choosing a field that offers an income worth the education.

Comment: Thankfully you've chosen a graph which shows median earnings, not mean, so none of the categories are skewed by the top .1% of earners.  You're right, however, that it doesn't say anything about the standard deviation (width of the bell), which is an important component of risk analysis.

Comment: I know you are a numbers guy, so your comment is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wish there were a blanket answer to your question.  It is very accurate that about half the salary difference from a degree is in signaling, which tells you how valuable it is as a signal.  The problem is this is an average.

Intermittently I teach a class in financial planning.  I require students to state their personal goals in concrete terms so that anyone who saw their list could buy the homes, cars, vacations and so forth they want in life.  They also have to either state two jobs they would like to do in one location or two places they would like to do one job in.

Salaries are very geography dependent.  Additionally, some jobs are very geography dependent.  If you are planning on staying in your hometown, then a degree is less worthwhile unless there just happens to be a match between the needs in your town and your degree.

Likewise, undergraduate degrees are generic to some degree.  The same textbooks are used all around the United States, including the Ivy League schools.  If you do not stand out in some way, then you have a generic degree.  That might be useful, but it might just make you part of the crowd.

Despite the griping about the liberal arts, they get jobs, and the jobs sometimes pay more than the jobs customarily thought of as high paying.  Nonetheless, things are not equal in college.  Math skills are critical for future salaries, even in art.  When the 2008 financial crisis hit, the primary determinant of whether an art major was hired was their math scores and the highest level of math completed.

If you say, "I will take the minimum," then unless you are an aerospace engineering student or something similar, it may mean your degree doesn't matter.  Art students who can do math can be curators and run the business of art.  Education majors who can do math can be bank loan officers.

The second thing everyone should take is one class in computer programming.  It isn't to become a programmer.  Programming requires a very special way of thinking about problems.  This skill is highly prized and most people with will never write a single line of software in their future employment.  It isn't about learning to build a video game or an accounts receivable program; it is about learning to think in algorithms.

Master English.  When I tell students who are learning to write business plans what they are to do, I remind them that this is a five million dollar book.  It has an audience of one person, maybe five.  Ten at most.  Venture capitalists will tell you the book must be an A+, they don't fund A or A- quality work.  It has to be a Stephen King best seller.  You cannot have errors in comma placement.  You need word choice that matches your audience and the nature of your business.

If you do the minimum and get your degree, then you have a very good chance of getting the minimum out of it in terms of pay.

I said about half was signaling.  About one-quarter of the pay is in field-specific technical skills.  The other quarter in value comes from forcing your mind to stretch in ways it doesn't want to.  Students who just want to learn the skills in their field miss a lot of pay.  That is precisely what an associates degree is.  You learn exactly what you need to know to do a job.

Build a spreadsheet.  If you cannot build a spreadsheet, then this is a bad sign as to your future pay.  Spreadsheets are a core employment skill.  Build a spreadsheet using either two jobs in one town or one job in either of two locations.  Calculate what the schooling is worth.

Some fields do not require college.  Think through what you want to do.  Education is valuable, but *only* if it is *education* and not job training.  If your brain hurts, then it is physically growing.  Your brain has to lay down pathways for you to learn new things.  That is why schooling is so hard.  Your brain has to physically grow to learn new things.  Your brain will fight tooth and nail to prevent that.  That is what makes college so valuable.  It makes your brain grow.  The skills are nice too.

Finally, learn to mimic people who are better at things than you are.  Look through the prose I presented here.  Look at the hyphens between some words.  Would you have put hyphens there?  I used prose instead of text.  What would you have used?  Should you have used parentheses in the places that you used them, or were there better ways to express the same idea?  If you do not know the answers to these questions, visit the English department.

Answer (score 1):

1.Are student loans justifiable debt?

**Depends on your situation.**

I come from a small rural community where there are very few residents of the community that could afford to send their kids to post-secondary without the help of financial aid. Not everybody can get parental help with expenses, and that's okay.

My first two years at college were in a different province. I had to get student loans to help with everything - tuition, books, rent, groceries, gas - therefore, my loans were not directly related to the course I was taking at the time.

I know I definitely had time to get a job while completing that program - but I didn't. I was struggling with anxiety and depression issues at the time and *for me* it just wasn't feasible. I completed a two-year Graphic Design program that I've barely used since, and makes up half of my student debt, but I regret nothing because I used that time to get my head on straight and figure out how to handle my issues. Justifiable financially? Nope. Justifiable personally? Absolutely.

2.What to consider before applying for student loans?

What course/program/degree/etc. are you looking at? How labour intensive are they? Will you have enough free time for a part time job? **If you can swing it, do it.** It might suck not being able to hang with your friends all the time, but future you will thank you *profusely*.

If your chosen course/program/degree/etc. will take up every moment of your life for the next x-number of years, you won't have time to work. **Look for scholarships.** Apply to any and all you can find that even remotely relates to you and your educational field. I've seen scholarships go to people who have barely met the requirements for the application, but have gotten it anyway because they were the only one to apply. You never know!

Budget out first. Are you relocating for school? You might automatically look for on-campus housing like dorms and such, which are awesome in terms of convenience. However, when I relocated the first time, I attended the community college that shared a campus with the local university. When I looked into it, the residences on campus were priced at the university level - more than double my tuition for a semester. I looked around town and found a much better priced boarding house near the college and saved myself a few grand. **Look around for options before settling** - there might be something better if you take the time to search for it.

Living off-campus creates the issue of travel - will you have a car? Take the bus? Are you close enough to walk? And don't forget about the other basics - food, cellphone, and credit cards you may have (some banks offer a student line of credit). **The art of budgeting is a wonderful thing.**

All of these things you should definitely keep in mind, but the most important thing to look at has been mentioned many times already: **Will you be able to afford to pay back your loans on whatever job you get with your program?** Protip -> Start by looking up entry-level jobs in your field, because this is where monthly payments might get the better of you. It's all well and good to get into a field where experts make >$100k, but how long will you have to work until you get to that point? **Everyone starts at the bottom,** which lasts for a indeterminate amount of time. Make sure you plan for that (also, be prepared -
 experience is the bane of every new-graduates existence. Everyone wants it, but nobody wants to give it).

Comment: You mentioned "I went to school in a different province" -- that implies that you are not in the United States, perhaps in Canada.  (The question is tagged united-states, perhaps that was added after you answered.) The job market is very different in the US -- many jobs require "a college degree" in the US that don't in Canada. (And in the US "a college degree" usually means "a 4-year college degree" -- in the US an institution is not considered a university unless it offers degrees beyond the 4 years for a BS.)